# React: Switch out rendered component

Tags: reactjs, components, rendering, render

Quite new at this and have a question with something that I feel like should be an easy answer.

I essentially have a page that has 5 titles. When I click on a title, it will render that component. I have that, but I don't know how to then make the 5 titles go away? The component that is rendered just shows up below the titles and I want them to switch entirely. Have done a lot of googling and can't seem to get it right.

*XYZ.js*

```
import '../App.css';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Chat from './chat.js';

export class XYZ extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showChat: false,
        };
        this._onChatClick = this._onChatClick.bind(this);
    }

    _onChatClick() {
        this.setState({
            showChat: !this.state.showChat,

        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="yyy">
                <div className="xxx">

                    <div className="chatBody">
                        <Button className="chatTitle" onClick={this._onChatClick}>
                            Chat xxz
                        </Button>
                        {this.state.showChat ?
                            <Chat /> : null
                        }
                    </div>
                     <div>
                          ....brevity
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default XYZ;
```

Thank you for any help!! Can supply additional files if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Can' comment but I guess that you want `<Button className="chatTitle">` to disappear when you click on it.

You need to either put it in the place of the `null` in your ternary operator or put another conditional rendering on top of the existing one, like:

```
{!this.state.showChat && <Button className="chatTitle">Chat xxz</Button>}
```